# Tried to duplicate site in local environment but loading blank

Tags: installation

I'm trying to duplicate an existing Craft CMS site by moving it from an online server to a local installation using MAMP. I have copied the /craft folder and all files in the root of /public_html (including the htaccess file). I have exported and reimported the database using PHPMyAdmin.

But now when I go to localhost:8888 I get a "server not found" error because I've been redirected to www.localhost — is this the issue? I tried swapping out the htaccess file to the default one from the craft installation packet but then instead of getting a server not found I get blank pages.

Any ideas? I'm pretty sure the database imported correctly because I could login to /admin before I moved the /craft folder to the local server.

Comment: A hint from crafts documentation "If you’re getting a 404, your server might not be configured to redirect would-be 404’s to index.php correctly. Try going to http://example.com/index.php/admin or http://example.com/index.php?p=admin instead" so try adding a "index.php" since you have to change your mamp configuration to go to your index.php file directly otherwise

Comment: By the way did you move your `index.php` file? Usually that file is in the public folder so if you didn't change your mamp  you would have to use `localhost:8888/public` anyway

Comment: Thanks @RobinSchambach. I ended it up fixing the issue by replacing the /craft folder with the original installation folder and then just replacing /craft/templates and /craft/plugins from the existing site.

Comment: Would you mind adding what worked for you as an official answer?  It might end up helping someone in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I ended it up fixing the issue by replacing the /craft folder with the original installation folder and then just replacing /craft/templates and /craft/plugins from the existing site.